# How can I re-order my X-axis so that my Samples are grouped based on the Group they belong to

Tags: r, ggplot2, phyloseq

[image]

Basically I have some graphs I am working on and they are facetted by Groups (there are four). The X axis are samples but as you can see my Groups are still showing blank samples from other groups. Is there a way to change this? I have posted my code below. Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

```
p = plot_bar(phyloseq_merged, "Samples", fill = "Class", facet_grid =~Location) 
p
```

Comment: You may get a quicker response by posting an issue to the `phyloseq` github page: https://github.com/joey711/phyloseq/issues

Answer (score 0):

added `facet_grid(~Example, scales="free")` and it removed the empty columns